# yii2 can't set cookie first visit

Tags: cookies, yii2

I want to set a cookie value at first visit.so I did this.

```
function init() {
    $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
    $cookies->add(new Cookie([
        'name' => 'aa',
        'value' => '111',
        'expire' => time()+86400,
        'domain' => '.xxx.cn',
        'path' => '/'
    ]));
｝
```

then I refresh the page, I get nothing(refresh page at least three times, aa value would be set in browser). I knew can't get the cookie value at the same request, but I still want to do that.Any way can do this?

Comment: try this: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/cookies-handling-in-yii-framework2-0/

Comment: @CrazzySkulll it's the same way

Comment: @KestrelBright Are you sure about `domain` value?! remove `domain` and try again.